# $.get returns the same array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I was getting the same array because I was doing the same thing. Wrong order of operations.

Comment: Your link never changes so you `$.get()` the same page. Changing `a` does not change the string that is contained in `b`

Comment: @PatrickEvans It did work, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another user spotted, your URL doesn't actually change because `b` is set once.

If you place `b` inside the function it will pick up the amended value `a`.

It might also be useful to use [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead of [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to allow your [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) request to complete before running it again.

```
var a = 1

function check() {
  var b = "https://example.com/" + a
  $.get(b, function(data){
    pg = $($.parseHTML(data.trim()))

    var c = pg.find(".someclass")[0]    
    var d = pg.find(".anotherclass")[0]

    if(c != undefined && d === undefined) { my code1; return a += 1;}
    if(d != undefined && c === undefined) { my code2; return a += 1;}
    setTimeout(check, 5000);
  })
}
check()
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what was wrong. About the setTimeout, it only executes the function one time, so i'll keep setInterval for now.

Comment: It does indeed. However, you’re setting a timeout as a callback - which is effectively a loop but without a fixed interval. Whichever works for you I guess.